# How to find required Android Marshmallow runtime permissions in code?

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow

I'm preparing my app to target Android 6.0 Marshmallow.

When setting the target api to 23, the app immediately crashes upon launch. There is no useful information in the logcat output. (It gives a "Requested window does not exist" IllegalStateException, but still, nothing actually useful like class name or line number.)

This is fine (not really), I eventually narrowed it down to my launch activity where I get the user's device IMEI code (TelephonyManager.getDeviceId()). There needs to be a runtime permission request added. I understand this.

However, the app has something like 60 classes across numerous activities, so there is a lot of code to sort through. How can I possibly search through the code to find all of the cases where runtime permissions are required?

Surely Google must have thought of an easy way for developers to track down where the permission requests are required? I thought perhaps commenting out the permissions in the manifest would trigger a compile-time error where the permissions are used, or something of the sort, but nope.

My current method is by going through the app and when it crashes, do like the above with my launch activity and very slowly narrow down where it is. This is extremely inefficient and time-consuming. I'm tempted to just leave it at API 22 for now, but I know sooner or later this will have to be done.

Comment: hi can you send the build grade XML File

Comment: Try Analyze > Inspect Code in Android Studio.

Comment: Thanks, but Inspect Code does not provide a solution for this.

Comment: Hello Try this for API level 23
http://stackoverflow.com/a/41221852/5488468

Answer (score 2):

Delete all AndroidManifest.xml permission.
Analyze -> Run Inspection by Name ->`Constant and Resource Type Mismatches` in Android Studio.
You can detect permission.
[image]

But this detection is not perfect...
Because this detects only method that contains this xmls files.
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/adt/idea/+/master/android/annotations/android
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/adt/idea/+/master/android/annotations/android/accounts/annotations.xml#118

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me is this :
Analyze -> Run Inspection by Name -> Missing Permissions