# Android, find all places in code to request permissions

Tags: java, android, android-permissions

I am working on an application for pre-Marshmallow devices. The source code was not written by me and the project itself is quite big.
I am currently making the app to request permissions when needed.

The question is: How to find all places in code where permission should be requested?
I am using Android Studio.

**EDIT**
Some people suggest to change api to 23 and just run the app and see the places where it crashes.
The problem is that the app does not crash in every place.

For example, running this code without a permission will crash the app:

```
TelephonyManager manager = (TelephonyManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
```

While this one just returns an empty array, instead of crashing.

```
final String[] SELF_PROJECTION = new String[]{
    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,};
Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver()
    .query(ContactsContract.Profile.CONTENT_URI, SELF_PROJECTION, null, null, null);
```

Also, Android Lint does not show these places. I'm not sure if it should be.

Comment: That's impossible to answer in the abstract. You have to request permissions from your UI. So, you need to determine where in your app you are using the secured APIs, then determine whether that is a permission that you should ask for up front (e.g., on first run of your app) or only when the user taps on some UI element (e.g., action bar item) requesting to use the code that needs the secured APIs.

Comment: @CommonsWare, I am asking for an easy way to determine those locations when you're not familiar with the project. I know what to do after that.

Comment: Maybe you compile against sdk 23. you can run inspection in android studio.

Comment: @blay, It just doesn't show these places, while other errors and warnings are shown.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34681480/794088

Comment: did you check @petey comment. that really shows Permission under Inspection tab

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=182165

Comment: Write some instrumentation tests and cover most of the code.

Comment: Also had this problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35965770/android-sdk23-find-places-to-update-and-request-permission

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the developer page regarding [security permissions](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html) :

> In almost all cases, however, a permission failure will be printed to the system log.

So run the app and search the log for "permissions" or similar.

Use unit testing to ensure coverage of all the places in the code where permissions may be required.

Comment: Although none of the answers helped me completely, this one was the best one.

Answer (score 2):

Add

```
lintOptions {
    enable 'MissingPermission'
}
```

in your `build.gradle`. This will show warnings after you build your application.

Comment: Did this actually show all your missing permissions?  It did nothing for me.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, compile targeting api 23, do not add in permissions code, run the app and see where it crashes.

Once you start pinpointing the locations then flip permissions on (via app settings) so you can get past that screen and then turn them back off so you can see if it crashes.

Logcat is pretty descriptive in letting you know that permissions are denied...

Comment: Yeah, forgot to mention that I've already tried that.
See my edit.

Comment: Yah, I see you wrote " The problem is that the app does not crash in every place." But if you look at logcat you'll see when a permission is denied. I'd suggest filtering by error logs and watching that as you play with the app

Comment: Btw, I had to do this on a project also. And this is how I solved it

Comment: Very tedious and error prone - how do you know you tested all the places in your app the need a permission?  A comprehensive tool is needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this trick: delete the dangerous permissions from the manifest. This way, you can test on pretty much any device, you'll be sure it will crash and you'll find the exact places where you need those permissions. This is how I did it anyway.

Answer (score -4):

Request all permissions you want at the first startup of your app.

It's not a **Best Practices**, but it is an **answer** of this question.

Comment: Don't Overwhelm the User
If the user is running Android 6.0 (API level 23) or later, the user has to grant your app its permissions while they are running the app. If you confront the user with a lot of requests for permissions at once, you may overwhelm the user and cause them to quit your app. Instead, you should ask for permissions as you need them. [Link](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/permissions/best-practices.html)