# Marshmallow permission

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-permissions, android-studio-2.1

I'm trying to check permission in activity as below,

```
int permission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNT);
```

But I'm getting error at `GET_ACCOUNT` as `Cannot resolve symbol 'GET_ACCOUNT'`.
Kindly help what code should I add to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Isn't it `GET_ACCOUNTS`? With an `S`?

Comment: @Mike M : It is GET_ACCOUNT only.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#GET_ACCOUNTS

Comment: @Mike M : No it's not working

Comment: Check your manifest import. It should be _import android.Manifest;_. May be you have imported with your project package name!

Comment: @Piyush : I have imported android.Manifest, Still same error!

Comment: Changes this too `Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS`

Comment: please share the error log.

Comment: My app works smoothly on API below 23, When i try it on API 23 (Marshmallow) it throws NullPointerException @Abraham Gharyali

Comment: Did u check your build version? Also your target version should be 23

Comment: I have tried Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS as well as Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNT, both showing same error @Piyush

Comment: @Piyush : App targeted version is 24

Comment: did you tried cleaning your project?

Comment: I tried cleaning project, Still same error! @Abraham

Comment: android.Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNT(S) works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code worked for me,

Declare below code as:

```
public static final int PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_GET_ACCOUNT = 133; // any number
```

Call following code in your onCreate method:

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(Activity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(SplashActivity.this,
                    new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                            Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
                            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                            Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS},
                    PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_GET_ACCOUNT);
        }else{
            //furtherCode
        }
    }else{
        //furtherCode
    }
```

in method onRequestPermissionsResult method,

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    switch(requestCode){
        case PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_GET_ACCOUNT :
            if(grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                Toast.makeText(this, "Granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(this, "No such permission to access account!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS
```

instead of

```
Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNT
```

Try like this

```
int permission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS);
```

Don't forget to add permission on your Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
```

Import this library in your class

```
import android.Manifest;
```

Comment: I wrote this line in onCreate() method @Anik Islam Abhi

Comment: Adding android.Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS working

Comment: Try this it may be work stackoverflow.com/a/41221852/5488468

Answer (score 0):

First GET_ACCOUNT is not defined in android.Manifest.permission, it is GET_ACCOUNTS

Second, change your Manifest file to use GET_ACCOUNTS

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
```

then in your code file i.e. java file write like this.

```
ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS);
```

Check documentation [GET_ACCOUTNS](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#GET_ACCOUNTS).